# Are questions about pastoral advising on topic?

Tags: discussion

So, I want to ask a question about *how* a pastor should counsel a grieving individual.  Specifically, I want to know what the signs are of an individual who is "stuck" in his or her grief, and what traditionally the church fathers, reformers, or modern counselors would recommend in such a situation.  This is common enough to be not "too localized" but I fear it would not be favorably received either.

I would imagine quotes from Thomas Oden or any noted Christian counselors, past or present, would support such an answer.

I would imagine that the "signs of stuck in grief" would also come from the same community.

But would such a question be considered "pastoral advice" and thus be off-topic?

Answer (score 2):

Sure would be nice if they hadn't purged all the "merged with" stuff from Area 51.   There was a "worship leaders" proposal which was merged in to Christianity, so if the answer is no, then you're in the perpetual StackExchange Catch 22 that happens when you've got a question that's not applicable to the site people who don't care about the site say it's applicable to and vice versa.

So, consider this the

## Yes

answer and upvote accordingly!

---

in any event, I think you've already phrased the question well enough to make it on topic without any causing any sort of a hubbub.

so, consider this the

## No

Answer and upvote accordingly.

---

and now, succumb to the meta catch 22. Where on the one hand you have french fries and on the other hand you have Vegemite and on the other hand there is no other hand!

Comment: See also: [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/1438 "Which makes me wonder why I bother with MSO at all.")

Comment: Er... what are the choices again?

Comment: I upvoted. So that's one yes, one no, and one vegemite, please.